# How to embed textbox values to href in HTML

Tags: html, sms

I am very new to programming. I would like to add a phone number and text message to the below code using values from text boxes, How to do that? Pls see the code below. in the user interface I need two text boxes and a send button. Send button will trigger this below code.

<a href="sms://+15552345678?body=Hello,%20World">Phone(+1) and ?body (sms://)

Answer (score 0):

If you’re on a supported mobile platform, you can try this way:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="handleSendMsg()" id="btn">Send a SMS message</a>
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Type Phone" />
<input type="text" id="msg" placeholder="Type Message" />

<script>
    var PhoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone")
    var Msg = document.getElementById("msg")

    function handleSendMsg() {
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function () {
            this.href = "sms:" + PhoneNumber.value + "?body=" + encodeURI(Msg.value);
            // console.log(btn) 
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Dear Mr. Tamal,
Thank you for your quick response, I tried the code, but unfortunately it is not working. it may be some mistake from my side, can you share the full code. I am using a supported mobile platform, because the the one line code in my question if activated in my mobile, first it will ask permission for opening my SMS service, if click open, the phone number will be populated in "to" section and "hello world" will be in message section. only we have to click "send"

Comment: i did some correction in answer please have a look. you can paste this code into any HTML document it will work. If first time one click not works then do double click on anchor tag. btw you can refactor this code as you want.

Comment: (SOLVED) 
Dear Tamal, This code runs perfectly as intended, Thank you so much for your time. One more thing I want to clarify, Is it possible to run one more similar script in the same html from the same input value. two anchor tag will be there Send SMS1 and Send SMS2. My intention is to add some constant values to messages internally.

Comment: I tried but last script only executing. What major changes need to be done? can you add one more tag in your code. Meanwhile I'll try with "If else"

Comment: I coudn't find a solution for the above. Pls help, I would like to run one more similar script in the same html from the same input value. two anchor tag will be there Send SMS1 and Send SMS2. My intention is to add some constant values to messages internally.

Comment: if you declare the variable by same name then first one will  replaced  by last one. if you want to two sms sending form then you can declare variable and id name different different. like first id and variable name btnOne and another is btnTwo and same for the input box